# Mobile Safari skips first seconds of HTML Audio on play()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I have an React Audio Player that uses a useAudio hook to manage the HTML5 audio. It works fine everywhere except Mobile Safari, where the sound begins a few seconds after the player starts playing.

What's odd is that I'm checking `canplaythrough` on the element before calling `HTMLAudioElement.play()`. So Safari fires `canplaythrough` and starts "playing" the audio, except that the audio doesn't actually start until a second or so in.

Here's a complete example on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/useaudioplayer-jvftw?file=/src/useAudio.tsx

To replicate, open in Mobile Safari and play the Audio.

Comment: I've had the same problem and posted an almost identical question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66052832/inconsistent-audio-playback-from-audio-tag-in-safari-on-laptop

Comment: (Try putting ‘JavaScript’ as a tag - might attract more attention).

Comment: @tonitone120 good idea

Comment: Not having trouble in my version of Safari.  When I click play, the "Bonjour" audio starts up almost immediately, including the techno-news beats beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case audio would play ok the 1st time.
And from the 2nd time and on, safari would skip some initial seconds.

Solved it by calling
`myAudio.load();`
just before
`myAudio.play();`

Comment: Thank you - this finally solved my problem after hours of trial and error. It's not clear what the cause of this bug is, as my audio is triggered by a click event. Safari refusing to cache the audio?

Comment: You are a livesaver omg